# Deleted VF Page, now getting Salesforce has blocked this package upgrade error

Tags: managed-package, package-install

We removed a Visualforce page and two components that were no longer used in our package, but kept the controller in and in tact with no changes. I know to delete the Apex controller you have to empty the page, package, push, THEN delete the controller. We figured it should be fine to remove these pages as the controller would still remain.

But now we get this error: `Salesforce has blocked this package upgrade because the new package version removes some Apex code that one or more Visualforce pages or global Visualforce components need in order to function. Please contact your partner with this error information. Provide these component names to your partner. Visualforce Page: NewRecord.`

This makes no sense as the Apex all the deleted items used is still in the package just like it was... Can we fix this situation to be able to avoid a patch org? I don't understand what Salesforce is complaining about here as no Apex was removed and it shouldn't need a patch whatsoever.

Comment: I would say you have to create a patch org to resolve this, upgrading first to the patch then this new version. The patch should empty the VF page and components, removing reference to the controllers.

Comment: After some more reading I think it has to do with the visualforce component that was in the packet that was also deleted. Removing the reference to the controller shouldn't be an issue if the controller is still there... Salesforce is so frustrating sometimes

Comment: @TylerDahle Did you delete the _component's_ Apex controller?

Comment: @DavidReed No the component is using the same controller. The apex is all there still. Which is why this is so frustrating, these should just be able to be gotten rid of.